# cannot install Ubuntu 13.04, install terminates and Windows loads

Tags: system-installation

I have a win 7 laptop tried Ubuntu worked fine but when I try to install the laptop restarts and Windows loads I really wanted to have Ubuntu. All drivers are up to date could someone help me out with this

Comment: What laptop is it? What CPU and GPU does it use?

Comment: Is a lg r490 with intel i5 ,gpu nvidia gforce with cuda

Answer (score 0):

Try to hit the F8 button a couple of times during startup (right after you turn it on, even before Windows starts). A menu should pop up where you can select where your laptop should start from. From here, select CD/CD-ROM or USB (depending on which medium you try to install Ubuntu from) with your arrow buttons and hit enter.

Comment: I have done that, works fine even try Ubuntu works fine is when u start to install, dogs screen pops up show process terminated and Windows loads or for me loads Ubuntu all over again since changed the bot priority